# Replacing Network Map and Notary on Corda

Tags: corda

We need to change our Corda Network infrastructure. Currently we are working with one network map, three notaries (RAFT) and four additional nodes.

We will replace our network map and one notary server (notaryCluster one) with new servers.

Our plan is to perform following steps:

```
1. Stop all Nodes
2. Change all  node.conf files needed to point to new networkmap and new notary 
3. Deploy Networkmap and Notary service in new servers from scratch (not reusing data from old notary and network map)
4. Start new network map, start new notary servers, and rest of nodes (not old network and notary)
```

Is this process correct to ensure existing transactions will remain in the systems and will be able to work with them?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to consider

**- Stop all Nodes**

You need to consider any flows that are currently in-flight to perform a clean shutdown of the node.
Version 3.1 of Corda adds a "Draining mode" feature, through which:

- Commands requiring to start new flows through RPC will be rejected.
- Scheduled flows due will be ignored.
- Initial P2P session messages will not be processed, meaning peers will not be able to initiate new flows involving the node.

**- Deploy Network map and Notary service in new servers from scratch (not reusing data from old notary and network map)**

You would want to keep data from the old notary, else the notary would lose track of states that have been consumed, and the network would lose the guarantee of preventing double spends